# Problema con redirecciones .htaccess en sitio Wordpress sub-carpeta

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Tengo dos Wordpress instalados en un mismo dominio que funcionan como si fueran sitios independientes.

- Original........:[`https://www.deiverbum.org`](https://www.deiverbum.org/)
- Sub-Folder..: [`https://app.www.deiverbum.org`](https://www.app.deiverbum.org/)

A la página principal del sitio en el sub-folder puedo acceder tanto así: `app.deiverbum.org` como así: `deiverbum.org/app`

Pero a las páginas que hay en el sitio del sub-folder no.

Por ejemplo, estoy creando una página de ayuda y considero que si pongo esta URL debería funcionar, pero no funciona: `app.deiverbum.org/ayuda`. Si intento acceder así me da error 500 ([prueba de que no funciona](https://app.deiverbum.org/ayuda)):

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at AAA@BBB to inform them of
>   the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just
>   before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Solamente puedo acceder si escribo la URL así: `deiverbum.org/app/ayuda` ([prueba de que sí funciona](https://deiverbum.org/app/ayuda))

¿Por qué no puedo hacer que funcione con el estilo `app.deiverbum.org`, si con la página principal funciona? ¿Se puede corregir esto con alguna regla de `.htaccess`.

He probado varias cosas, pero ninguna funciona.

Mi `.htaccess` está así en el sub-folder:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files xmlrpc.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files debug.log>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_START
Options -Indexes
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_END
#AIOWPS_DENY_BAD_QUERY_STRINGS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp:     [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http:    [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https:   [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(request|insert|union|declare|drop) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_DENY_BAD_QUERY_STRINGS_END
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_START
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 \,
RedirectMatch 403 \:
RedirectMatch 403 \;
RedirectMatch 403 \=
RedirectMatch 403 \[
RedirectMatch 403 \]
RedirectMatch 403 \^
RedirectMatch 403 \`
RedirectMatch 403 \{
RedirectMatch 403 \}
RedirectMatch 403 \~
RedirectMatch 403 \"
RedirectMatch 403 \$
RedirectMatch 403 \<
RedirectMatch 403 \>
RedirectMatch 403 \|
RedirectMatch 403 \.\.
RedirectMatch 403 \%0
RedirectMatch 403 \%A
RedirectMatch 403 \%B
RedirectMatch 403 \%C
RedirectMatch 403 \%D
RedirectMatch 403 \%E
RedirectMatch 403 \%F
RedirectMatch 403 \%22
RedirectMatch 403 \%27
RedirectMatch 403 \%28
RedirectMatch 403 \%29
RedirectMatch 403 \%3C
RedirectMatch 403 \%3E
RedirectMatch 403 \%3F
RedirectMatch 403 \%5B
RedirectMatch 403 \%5C
RedirectMatch 403 \%5D
RedirectMatch 403 \%7B
RedirectMatch 403 \%7C
RedirectMatch 403 \%7D
# COMMON PATTERNS
Redirectmatch 403 \_vpi
RedirectMatch 403 \.inc
Redirectmatch 403 xAou6
Redirectmatch 403 db\_name
Redirectmatch 403 select\(
Redirectmatch 403 convert\(
Redirectmatch 403 \/query\/
RedirectMatch 403 ImpEvData
Redirectmatch 403 \.XMLHTTP
Redirectmatch 403 proxydeny
RedirectMatch 403 function\.
Redirectmatch 403 remoteFile
Redirectmatch 403 servername
Redirectmatch 403 \&rptmode\=
Redirectmatch 403 sys\_cpanel
RedirectMatch 403 db\_connect
RedirectMatch 403 doeditconfig
RedirectMatch 403 check\_proxy
Redirectmatch 403 system\_user
Redirectmatch 403 \/\(null\)\/
Redirectmatch 403 clientrequest
Redirectmatch 403 option\_value
RedirectMatch 403 ref\.outcontrol
# SPECIFIC EXPLOITS
RedirectMatch 403 errors\.
RedirectMatch 403 config\.
RedirectMatch 403 include\.
RedirectMatch 403 display\.
RedirectMatch 403 register\.
Redirectmatch 403 password\.
RedirectMatch 403 maincore\.
RedirectMatch 403 authorize\.
Redirectmatch 403 macromates\.
RedirectMatch 403 head\_auth\.
RedirectMatch 403 submit\_links\.
RedirectMatch 403 change\_action\.
Redirectmatch 403 com\_facileforms\/
RedirectMatch 403 admin\_db\_utilities\.
RedirectMatch 403 admin\.webring\.docs\.
Redirectmatch 403 Table\/Latest\/index\.
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_ADVANCED_CHAR_STRING_FILTER_END
#AIOWPS_SIX_G_BLACKLIST_START
# 6G FIREWALL/BLACKLIST
# @ https://perishablepress.com/6g/

# 6G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (eval\() [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:)(.*)(;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode)(.*)(\() [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)(.*)script(.*)(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\|\.\.\.|\.\./|~|`|<|>|\|) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|etc/passwd|self/environ) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (thumbs?(_editor|open)?|tim(thumb)?)\.php [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ('|\")(.*)(drop|insert|md5|select|union) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(connect|debug|move|put|trace|track) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REFERRERS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (semalt.com|todaperfeita) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 6G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)([a-z0-9]{2000,})
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(https?|ftp|php):/
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(base64_encode)(.*)(\()
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(=\'|=\%27|/\'/?)\.
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(\$(\&)?|\*|\"|\.|,|&|&amp;?)/?$
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\\"\\")
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(~|`|<|>|:|;|,|%|\|\s|\{|\}|\[|\]|\|)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(=|\$&|_mm|cgi-|etc/passwd|muieblack)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)(&pws=0|_vti_|\(null\)|\{\$itemURL\}|echo(.*)kae|etc/passwd|eval\(|self/environ)
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)\.(aspx?|bash|bak?|cfg|cgi|dll|exe|git|hg|ini|jsp|log|mdb|out|sql|svn|swp|tar|rar|rdf)$
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/(^$|(wp-)?config|mobiquo|phpinfo|shell|sqlpatch|thumb|thumb_editor|thumbopen|timthumb|webshell)\.php
</IfModule>

# 6G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ([a-z0-9]{2000,}) bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (archive.org|binlar|casper|checkpriv|choppy|clshttp|cmsworld|diavol|dotbot|extract|feedfinder|flicky|g00g1e|harvest|heritrix|httrack|kmccrew|loader|miner|nikto|nutch|planetwork|postrank|purebot|pycurl|python|seekerspider|siclab|skygrid|sqlmap|sucker|turnit|vikspider|winhttp|xxxyy|youda|zmeu|zune) bad_bot

# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
</IfModule>

# Apache >= 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
<RequireAll>
Require all Granted
Require not env bad_bot
</RequireAll>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_SIX_G_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_START
# 5G BLACKLIST/FIREWALL (2013)
# @ http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

# 5G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|='$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (binlar|casper|cmsworldmap|comodo|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|turnit|vikspider|zmeu) keep_out
<limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=keep_out
</limit>
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 (https?|ftp|php)\://
RedirectMatch 403 /(https?|ima|ucp)/
RedirectMatch 403 /(Permanent|Better)$
RedirectMatch 403 (\=\\\'|\=\\%27|/\\\'/?|\)\.css\()$
RedirectMatch 403 (\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")
RedirectMatch 403 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
RedirectMatch 403 /(contac|fpw|install|pingserver|register)\.php$
RedirectMatch 403 (base64|crossdomain|localhost|wwwroot|e107\_)
RedirectMatch 403 (eval\(|\_vti\_|\(null\)|echo.*kae|config\.xml)
RedirectMatch 403 \.well\-known/host\-meta
RedirectMatch 403 /function\.array\-rand
RedirectMatch 403 \)\;\$\(this\)\.html\(
RedirectMatch 403 proc/self/environ
RedirectMatch 403 msnbot\.htm\)\.\_
RedirectMatch 403 /ref\.outcontrol
RedirectMatch 403 com\_cropimage
RedirectMatch 403 indonesia\.htm
RedirectMatch 403 \{\$itemURL\}
RedirectMatch 403 function\(\)
RedirectMatch 403 labels\.rdf
RedirectMatch 403 /playing.php
RedirectMatch 403 muieblackcat
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.*)?\.deiverbum\.org/app [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_PREVENT_IMAGE_HOTLINKS_END
# END All In One WP Security

# Use PHP5.6 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /app/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /app/themedy_features/misa/ /app/misa/
Redirect 301 /app/themedy_features/breviario/ /app/breviario/
#Redirect 301 /app/ayuda/ deiverbum.org/app
```

Hay muchas reglas de esas que no entiendo, las ha agregado mi plugin de seguridad o mi hosting, debido (creo) al certificado SSL.

Comment: ¿Hay algún error en el log de apache?  Lo has checando

Comment: @simon no tengo acceso al log de Apache, es un hosting compartido. Tampoco puedo cambiar el archivo de configuración de Apache por el mismo motivo. Sólo puedo modificar el `.htaccess`

Comment: Bueno ,las dos causas más comunes de este error son un archivo .htaccess dañado y que excede el límite de memoria PHP de su servidor.  El archivo .htaccess en su directorio de WordPress puede corromperse después de instalar un complemento o realizar otro cambio en su sitio de WordPress.  La solución es simple.  Todo lo que necesitas hacer es crear un nuevo archivo .htaccess.